# Adding hover effect to listview item (windows universal 10)

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app

i'm trying to add an hover effect to listview item.
i can add an hover effect when the data is in the same page.

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Key="ListViewItemHover">
    <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="Red" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Content1" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="Blue" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Content1" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content1"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

 <ListView Height="200">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListViewItem Width="100" Margin="10,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemHover}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="120"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Image Source="" Grid.Row="0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
                <TextBlock Text="1" Grid.Row="2" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            </Grid>
        </ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem Width="100" Margin="10,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemHover}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="120"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Image Source="" Grid.Row="0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="2" Grid.Row="1" />
                <TextBlock Text="2" Grid.Row="2"  TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            </Grid>
        </ListViewItem>
    </ListView>
```

however when using resource dictionary it fails.

```
<ListView Height="200" Grid.Row="1" Name="test" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource row_items}">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>

<DataTemplate x:Key="row_items">
    <ListViewItem Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemHover}">
        <Grid Width="100" Margin="10,0,0,0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="120"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Image Source="{Binding data, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding data1, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="1"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding data2, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="2" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </Grid>
    </ListViewItem>
</DataTemplate>
```

i assume that the data template is causing the issue. however how do i fix it.
are there any good tutorials on this matter. i found a lot for wpf but not for universal.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you are right. Your `DataTemplate` is the cause of your issue.

`ListView.ItemTemplate` sets the `DataTemplate` used to display each item. The `DataTemplate` is used inside the `ListViewItem`, exactly it used as the content of the `ContentPresenter`, you can find this in Visual Studio's **Live Visual Tree**:
[image]

So to fix it, we need change the `DataTemplate` like:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="row_items">
    <Grid Width="100" Margin="10,0,0,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="120"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image Source="{Binding data, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding data1, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding data2, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="2" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

And to use the `ListViewItemHover` style, we need set the [`ItemContainerStyle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle.aspx) property. This property gets or sets the style that is used when rendering the item containers. Setting this property equals to setting `Style` for `ListViewItem`.

```
<ListView Name="test"
          Grid.Row="1"
          Height="200"
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemHover}"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource row_items}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding list}">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

Comment: is there a way to target a control with name "test"?
example i want to target a textblock in this listview with name "test".

Comment: @user3884957: There are several ways to to access a named control inside DataTemplate, it depends on your scenario. You can search it on Internet. If you still have issues about this, I suggest you ask a new question about your new issue specifically.

Comment: thanks for the response

<TextBlock Text="{Binding data1, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="1" Name="test"/>

this is located in my DataTemplate

Comment: @user3884957: I think this question is irrelevant to the original question. So please ask a new question to clarify your scenario and specific problem. Thanks.